# Receive HTTP Response in POST request without navigating to new page

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I hope the question isn't too vague so I will try to explain it better.

I am integrating a payment software in a PrestaShop module. I am sending the payment info via post to a URL and I do not receive the response right away but get navigated to a success page instead. After 10 minutes or so the payment system will send an HTTP POST request to a URL of my choice. I need to get the info and do a check on the server in the background wheater the response is 200 or 500, etc.

How do I listen for / get the incoming HTTP POST request at the server without loading a controller and view?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar problems, I often use two methods. The first is multiple queries using ajax, a background check from time to time. The second is to use websocket.

Comment: This is not what OP asked for